# How to detect end of page for PDF in php (laravel)

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have the following php code that converts html blade and show it on PDF file:

```
public function generatePDF(Request $request)
{
    PDF::SetTitle('myPDF');
    PDF::AddPage();
    $html_content = $view->render();
    PDF::AddPage();
    PDF::writeHTML($html_content, true, false, true, false, '');
    PDF::Output('myPDF.pdf'); }
```

$view is a laravel blade takes many paragraphs(string) with different lengths form database then the previous code show them on PDF file in a specific pattern.

What i want is to guarantee that no paragraph will split between two pages, for example if there is a paragraph of 4 lines and only two lines remains from the first page, then the whole paragraph should start from the second page.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should need to use this package instead for better library when dealing with PDF.

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

This is quite most developers has been using on the PDF development to every projects and even simpler to integrate and use.

For hard core solution, you may use this library but you need to code in a native PHP coding. Here is the online doc of the Library. http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: there's a method in DomPDF 'setPaper()', so you can control the height and width of your paper that way.

Comment: I tried something like this but it was not useful! I do not know the lengths of the paragraphs or their order, I need an effective solution

Comment: had you tried the original PDF creator. the FPDF ? but this is very native in coding that you need to code it by using the cell method not HTML height and width. or inches as well.

Comment: TCPDF is a bit HTML friendly compare teo FPDF, but FPDF is better for native PHP coders. in terms of client requirements,  sometimes i'm still using the FPDF to meet the client satisfaction.

Comment: in FPDF you can check the height instantly while its doing the job something like.

$pdf->cell(20,50,"content or paragraph_here");

on the next line, you can check the current height already so in that case, you can call the $pdf->addPage() below to it.